# Where to alloc when using dependency injection and mock objects

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, tdd

I understand that in order to facilitate the testing process, one should use dependency injection as a design principle. If I'm not wrong, instead of allocating an object I'm going to use, I should declare it as public and let someone else do the job; in this case when testing and creating the mock. However, in order to use the real object, eventually, I will have to allocate it. But, where?

I used lazy instantiation to allow the mock object to take place over the real one, and when it does't, when I'm running the app, the real object will be used. It gets the job done but I was told that it's not a good practice to use lazy instantiation in that way; specially, when the object to be allocated requires different parameters. For example, a NSURLConnection.

The class using the object is a ViewController, so it is the last "client". There's no other class that I can delegate the allocation of the object, and if I allocated it in, let's say, viewDidLoad then I won't be able to mock that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why Dependency Injection(DI) containers are created. They are responsible for creating the instances of the objects at the runtime. You don't have to write a single line of code in your classes for this when you wire it up correctly. Typically all classes state their dependencies in their constructors.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(ISomeDependency dependency)
    {
        //assing dependency to a field etc
    }
}
```

When your application needs to create an instance of `SomeClass` type, it delegates it to the DI container. The container will inspect the constructor and find out it will have to provide an instance of `ISomeDependency` first. Containers keep a list of the concrete types that are mapped to an abstraction. These lists are created by code,configuration files or some conventions. When the container finds the concrete type for `ISomeDependency` interface it tries to create an instance of it with the same way. This goes on until all dependencies are provided and you get an instance of `SomeClass`. These dependencies can also be easily replaced with test doubles in your unit tests.

DI containers are complex libraries and they do more than creating object graphs. They also manage the lifetime of the objects they create. Since you have not created the object yourself, you have to notify the container when it is not needed anymore. Your application should have a second hook to the container for this. These hooks are specific to the each platform and you can easily find examples for wiring up a popular container.